# Exercise band lateral walk muscles used?

Tags: muscle, exercise-equipment, workout-types

What muscles are used  in sidewalking with a resistance band? 
[image]

Comment: When I saw the title I thought this question was literally going to be about walking on a sidewalk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Prime Movers**

- **Hip Abductors:**  Gluteus Medius & Minimus
- **Hip Adductors:**  Adductor Longus, Brevis & Maximus

[image]

> **Contraction Types**

- **Concentric Contraction:** Muscle is *Shortening* and Generating Force
- **Eccentric Contraction:**  Muscle is *Lengthening* and Generating Force

---

### Muscle Activation

> **During each Lateral Step** 
>   *(Only looking at activation of key hip muscles)*

[image]

**1. Leading (or Moving Leg)**: Concentric Contraction of the Hip Abductors 
 *(Generating force to both stretch the band & advance
    your leg)*

**2. Trailing (or Stance Leg)**: Eccentric Contraction of the Hip Abductors 
*(controlling the movement)*

> **After the Step** 
>   
> The leading leg now becomes the weight bearing leg (or stance leg).

[image]

**3. Leading (or Stance Leg):** Concentric Contraction of the Hip **Add**uctors 
 *(controlling the movement)*

**4. Trailing (or Moving Leg):** Eccentric Contraction of the Hip Abductors
 *(controlling the movement)*
***Note:*** The stretched elastic band generates the force to advance your trailing leg

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thanks for your high quality contributions!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](https://www.verywell.com/g00/lateral-band-walking-exercise-3120456), the primary muscle being exercised is the *[gluteus medius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluteus_medius_muscle)*.

[image: Illustration of glutueal muscles including the gluteus medius]

Comment: Given that there are two muscles pictured, can you summarize here why the one over the other? That way if "this page" goes away, the answer still makes sense.

Comment: @JohnP: Quite honestly, they don't really explain it beyond saying that that's what the exercise targets and "If you're doing it correctly, you should feel it in your gluteus medius!"